# Does having a SSL certificate for a domain name mean that all child nameservers of that domain are secured too?

Tags: ssl, dns, hosting, nameservers

How exactly are SSL certificates configured? I read that having an asterisk before the domain name(*.example.com) means that all child nameservers are secured too but I do not have the option to add the asterisk on the website that I bought my domain name and SSL

I have a domain name (example.com) linked to an IP address. I then create a child nameserver for the same domain name (ns1.example.com) linked to a different IP address. When I access the main website, the request is secured but that's not the case for the child nameserver. Do I have to configure my SSL certificate to support child nameservers?

Comment: *" all child nameservers are secured too"* - There is no such thing as "child nameservers". Did you mean subdomains? In general you need a certificate which covers all domains and subdomains and subsubdomains you want to use. This can be separate certificates for each of these, can be a single certificate for multiple domains including wildcard certificates.

Comment: Yes I meant subdomains (mentioned it as "child nameservers" as that's what it's called on my cPanel). Makes sense maybe my SSL does not cover sub-domains. Is there a way where I can verify what my SSL covers and what it doesn't? Thanks

Comment: *"Is there a way where I can verify what my SSL covers and what it doesn't?"* - look at the details of the certificate(s) you got. There is a subject alternative names (SAN) section were all domains are mentioned. Wildcard domains can occur there too but you must understand what they mean: \*.example.com covers foo.example.com and bar.example.com but it will not cover example.com or www.foo.example.com. If you want these domains covered then they also need to be included in the SAN or you need to have separate certificates for these.